# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT with SCNView and UIView Conflicting

Tags: swift, scenekit

i get the error on this line of code

```
let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
```

and in the console i get this

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1a7a33ed8) to 'SCNView'     (0x1a6cd79d0)
```

I looked this up and my case seems to be very different from others. I looked up to make sure i didnt have any connections in my Main Storyboard and I have no idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

ok the problem was that i accidentally deleted the scnview that was attached to my game view controller